# Any email clients for Linux with capability of sending an email multiple times to mail-list recipients individually?

Tags: linux, email, smtp

Any email clients for Linux with capability of sending an email multiple times to mail-list recipients individually?
Up to 30 recipients, if it is important.

P.S. No, python script does not work anymore as mail server somehow started to automatically think about my SMTP connection it sends spam (while it's not). Apparently something similar to user-agent analysis going on...

Comment: The client won't change what your Mailserver thinks about the same email being sent 30 times. I do agree with the Mailserver, though: this is a classical case of sending a single email with the recipients in BCC, not for sending 30 emails.

Comment: No, BCC is not a professional solution. Edited my question.

Comment: Sending 30 emails is the unprofessional solution! Now it's two equally valid opinions in the room with no arguments to back either up. Let's figure out what you need, you probably have a good reason! What problem are you solving by sending 30 separate emails?

Comment: @Marcus certain types of email now have to include one-click unsubscribe links, which means that a single email copied as-is to more than one recipient can’t work. Perhaps that’s what’s going on here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There's Thunderbird with its large, complicated, and ever-changing plugin interface. Which supports the mailmerge plugin, which, at least a couple of years back, used to be a way to send serial email, even with filled in names etc if you desired.

Nowadays, email providers tend to recognize nearly identical emails sent in short succession as potentially compromised email client. So, your mileage might vary, depending on your provider.

I never had troubles with your number of recipients in BCC, which is why I'd recommend that as easy and professional solution.